# Check if gridview row is selected or not with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have the following situation: I have an asp gridview that I have implemented row selection with javascript (I can select a row by clicking on every cell of it). The fired event is onclick through javascript and I am encountering a problem. When I try to edit te content of that row, through row edit command, at the moment I click on the textbox to focus on it, the row click event is fired again and I lose focus of the textbox. This way I have the desired effect that I can select a gridview by clicking everywhere, but I cannot edit the contents of the row.

Enable full row select on code behind:

```
protected void gvMyQuizz_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to show the questions of the quiz";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvMyQuizz,"Select$"+e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

The most helpful thing would be if I can create a javascript function that can check if the row that i being clicked is already selected, so I can return false, else select$row, but I haven't found much help online. I need to finish this through javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have changed the attribute that is added to the row on the onclick event:

```
protected void gvMyQuizz_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to show the questions of the quiz";
                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvMyQuizz, "selectRow(" + e.Row.RowIndex+");");
            }
        }
```

Javascript:

```
function selectRow(index) {

            var $selected = $("#gvMyQuizz .alt");
            if ($selected.length == 0) {
                console.log('nothing');
            } else if ($selected.length == 1) {
                console.log('one');
            } else {
                console.log('problem');
            }
        }
```

A function that I get when the row is clicked, but this is fired only once, I don't know why:

```
$("[id*=gvMyQuizz] td").click(function () {
            console.log('clicked');
        });
```

Is someone can figure out what is missing can help solve the issue. If the function that I fire when clicked is repeated, I can check there whether it is selected or not through this [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1756884.aspx?How+to+check+whether+any+row+selected+or+not+in+gridview+by+jquery).

Comment: There's this event called on selected index change. Try using that

Comment: I am already using this event on my gridview for other purposes. Can you please explain what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

*Edited*

If you want to handle row selection with your onclick event, the most straightforward option to check whether the row you have clicked is currently selected is to keep a hidden field running at the server end. This field would contain the index of the currently selected row. You would still have to trigger a post back to the server to update this value in your row selection logic with something like

```
<input id="inp_row_index" type="hidden" runat="server" />

function select(rowIndex) {
    document.getElementById('<%=inp_row_index.ClientID %>').value = rowIndex;
    <%=Page.GetPostBackEventReference(inp_row_index) %>
}
```

This is basically a summary of the approach described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79822/How-to-handle-a-selected-row-in-GridView-on-the-cl

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my explanation. I want to keep the click everywhere selection, but I do not want to fire it when that row is already selected. I believe it is not that difficult, just it is needed to check whether that row is already or not selected. I am just hoping for a javascript way to check this. @ChronoMTB - the links you pointed were for code behind events, which are not the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for then.

Comment: Use case:
You have gridview1, whose rows can be selected by clicking everywhere on the row. You select row 1. Now you want to edit the row data through the action edit command. When you click on the textbox containing the text, in stand of getting focus you trigger a refresh since the row has been clicked so it is selected again. I want to check when the row is being clicked on client side (javascript) to check if it is already selected. If yes , return false, else select$rowindex. Everything must be on clientside, since no postbacks must be triggered if not needed.

Comment: @g_brahimaj I have edited my answer. If that doesn't cover your case, I suggest that you add some stripped-down code for your gridview with more details on what you want to accomplish. If you want this to be a purely client-side solution, I cannot see a lot of reason behind using an asp gridview.